# Adding timeline to ListAnimate

Tags: graphics3d, list-manipulation, animation

I want to add time in the `ListAnimate` so that after I exporting the video I can see the graph changes by time. For example I have a graph that is changes by time, so I want to show in the animation at the time is this the graph is like this, and the graph would be slowly changes by time. How do you do that?

**Edit :** This is my working code:

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
a = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] /. t -> 0;
ic = {u[x, 0] == Cos[\[Pi]*x] + 2 Cos[3 \[Pi]*x], a == Cos[\[Pi]*x]};
solu3 = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}]
list22 = Table[
   Plot3D[solu3[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {u, -4, 4}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
    MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MaxRecursion -> 5], {t, 0, 2, 0.01}];
ListAnimate[list22, 40]
```

Comment: Can you provide data to work on and the code you have so far that produces your `ListAnimate`?

Answer (score 2):

You did not give an example, but you could always add the time to the ListPlot title?

[image]

Code

```
data = Table[Plot[Sin[t x], {x,0,10}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"Time ", t}]], {t,0,20,.5}];
ListAnimate[data, AnimationRate -> 1]
```